# Using JSON Api URL EmberJS

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I normally get data from a service I created, a hard-coded JSON. But I need to take the JSON from an URL.

This is my twiddle :

https://ember-twiddle.com/b9cd8b1b3418d876f88235c4aa99e268?openFiles=templates.pic.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs14

How can I add a URL as a source instead of calling it from the service 'pics'? I tried something but got errors and couldn't do anything. I'm very new at this.

I tried

```
model() {
   return $.getJSON('/my-url');
}
```

But I get this error :

```
Mirage: Your Ember app tried to GET 'my URL', but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route that matches this path in your mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?
```

I totally had no idea about the error because I don't use mirage, I created it yeah but didn't use in any part of the project.

Then I tried :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        this.get('my Json url', () => {
            return [];
        });
    }
});
```

Now chrome's devTool doesn't give any error but all I see is a blank-page. Is this all wrong or is it something about the `.hbs` files?

Any ideas?Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have ember-cli-mirage in your project dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I deleted it from npm-modules folder and packages.js. But I still see nothing but a blank page, with no errors at all. So I'm stucked. https://ember-twiddle.com/9c97721125a007fa52108ecdf9f72e0d?openFiles=models.list.js%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs  Maybe you can see what is wrong in the new twiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall `ember-cli-mirage` and go back to:

```
model() {
   return $.getJSON('/my-url');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that but still all I see is a blank page with no errors. Is it about my .hbs file? I can't figure out why. I used service before, now maybe I need to change somethin else? Can you please check my new twiddle, you can see it is all blank here. https://ember-twiddle.com/9c97721125a007fa52108ecdf9f72e0d?openFiles=models.list.js%2Ctemplates.components.image-list.hbs

Comment: I see 4 errors in console - first, Ember Twiddle uses HTTPS protocol and you try to load HTTP page - which raises Mixed Content error, so request from getJSON fails, then index route model raises an error because of that. You have to either try it locally instead of Ember Twiddle or you have to request HTTPS page instead of HTTP from Ember Twiddle.

Comment: I changed http:// to https:// but still nothing.. I must be missing something. How about my model list.js and .hbs files? do they seem okay?

Comment: You can't simply change protocols. I've tried your API page with HTTPS and it errored. It doesn't have HTTPS protocol available so it will still give you error. Look - this page won't load (there's no HTTPS for it): https://api.donanimhaber.com/api/v1/site/NewsSite?pageIndex=0&pageSize=15

Comment: this is not a page I created so I can't do anything on it, so are you saying there would be no problem if it was an https:// ? If so i I will talk to back-end guys and want them to do something. Or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Try this on your machine instead of Ember Twiddle so you won't have it to be HTTPS. Ember Twiddle forces it, but locally you can use HTTP, so recreate this on your machine and it should at least don't give you blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured what the problem was with some help :

Solution:

In my index.js, I should have used

```
{{image-list model=model.Data currentPos=currentPos }}
```

instead of

```
{{image-list model=model currentPos=currentPos }}
```

Also, I don't need any `model/*.js` because I get the `model()` from IndexRoute so I deleted those files. Thanks